# Is it possible and safe to replace functions as time() or sleep() for testing purposes?

Tags: python-3.x

I have to create and test some library that performs timestamped data processing. In order to achieve it I need to utilize some own source of compressed and shifted "virtual" time. The easiest way, transparent to any tested module is to simply replace time.time() and time.sleep() (probably these two is enough) with my own implementations. But is it safe, and reasonable?

Any smart alternatives?

Comment: We would need to see your own implementation of these functions to give a better answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I've done it, and it's basically as simple as you think. I made a class called FakeTime that responded to `__call__` to give the current time, which is set earlier in an attribute.

**However, you can do better.** This sort of thing is done all the time; it's called "mocking". [This blog post](http://alleged.org.uk/pdc/2011/09/03.html) mocks the clock, as you'd like to do:

```
import unittest
from mock import *
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import time

mock_time = Mock()
mock_time.return_value = time.mktime(datetime(2011, 6, 21).timetuple())

class TestCrawlerChecksDates(unittest.TestCase):
    @patch('time.time', mock_time)
    def test_mock_datetime_now(self):
        self.assertEqual(datetime(2011, 6, 21), datetime.now())
```

`mock`'s `@patch` is a little weird to get used to, but you can read the above as "For the duration of calls to the following method, swap his reference to `time.time` with `mock_time`."

Mocking `sleep`: it depends on what you want to do. Say you just wanted it to not sleep at all: `@mock.patch('time.sleep', lambda: None)` should work.